# Why does invoking std::make_tuple() with explicit template arguments cause "cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'T*&&' to lvalue of type 'T*'" error?

Tags: c++, templates

Why do we receive an error when explicitly providing the template arguments as below?

```
#include <tuple>
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int* ap = &a;
    // std::make_tuple<int*, int>(ap, a); // cause error "cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int*&&' to lvalue of type 'int*'
    std::make_tuple(ap, a); // fine
}
```

Comment: Do note that the whole purpose of the make functions is to not have to specify the type (expect make_unique and make_shared).

Comment: @NathanOliver, thanks for the reminder. I think in some cases, e.g., feeding literal values, we still need explicit arguments to be unambiguous?

Comment: In any cases when you need to be explicit there's no advantage in using these functions over the constructor like `std::tuple<int*,int>(....)`. And literal values are not ambiguous anyway, so this is not that case.

Comment: @DXZ That is what user defined literals and the built in literals are for.  If you want a `long`, use `0L`, `long long`, use `0LL`.